# Is there a "central distribution" for distributions for which the CLT doesn't apply?

Tags: variance, central-limit-theorem, scale-invariance, central-tendency

The central limit theorems state roughly that under a certain set of properties of a sampling process, the distribution of a statistic from that sample will converge in distribution to the normal distribution.

As the canonical example, let me take the basic central limit theorem: If we take i.i.d. samples $X_1,X_2...$ from a distribution $f$, then the sample average will converfe in diatribution to the normal distribution if

1. The mean of $f$ exists.
2. The variance of $f$ exists.

My question is:

Assume that $f$ does not have a variance, and that the sample average of an i.i.d.sample from $f$ does not converge in distribution to the normal distribution.

**Are there situations where this sample average nevertheless converges in distribution to some other (non-normal) distribution?**

In other words, is there a "central limit theorem" for distributions that don't converge to the nornal distribution?

Comment: Relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#A_generalized_central_limit_theorem).

Comment: @smith, very interesting.

Comment: Closely related answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29497 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8515.

Comment: Your statement that the sample average will converge to "the normal distribution" is false if by "the normal distribution" you mean the _standard_ normal distribution.  The statement is continues to be false even if you say that by the normal distribution you mean a normal distribution with mean equal to $\mu$, the mean of $f$, and variance equal to the variance of $f$.  The sample mean converges to the _constant_ $\mu$, that is, a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $0$, a far cry from what you seem to think happens.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, do you think that that is what I think, or that I was describing the CLT informally, since a precise formulation is not relevant to the question anyway?

Comment: I have no idea what you think; I can only go by what you write.  A precise formulation _is_ indeed relevant to the question, regardless of what you think; (I know what you have written about this issue).

Answer (score 2):

An answer is already found in the wikipedia link from the first comment by Smith.

Q: **Are there situations where this sample average nevertheless converges in distribution to some other (non-normal) distribution?**

A: Yes, iff a distribution is a [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) then it is a limit to sums of the type:

$$\zeta_n = \frac{\xi_1 + \xi_2 + \dots + \xi_n}{B_n} - A_n $$

with the $\xi$ independent and identically distributed random variables, $B_n>0$ and $\vert A_n\vert<\infty$

---

The type of distribution laws for $\xi$ that let the above sum converge to a stable distribution (the domain of attraction for that distribution) are described by a theorem in *'Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables' by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov (page 175 in the translated version 1954, [link via google](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=rYsZAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Theorem%202.%20In%20order%20that%20the%20distribution%20function%20F(x)%20belong%20to%20the%20domain%20of%20attraction%22))*

> Theorem 2.* In order that the distribution function F(x) belong to the domain of attraction of a stable law with the characteristic exponent $\alpha$ ($0 \leq \alpha \leq 2$) it is necessary and sufficient that
>
> 1) $$\frac{F(-x)}{1-F(x)} \to \frac{c_1}{c_2} \qquad \text{as }  k \to \infty$$
>
> 2) for every constant $k>0$
>
> $$\frac{1 - F(x) + F(-x)}{1-F(xk) + F(-kx)} \to k^\alpha \qquad \text{as }  k \to \infty$$

- *The theorem is attributed to

  - B.V. Gedenko 1939 (no online version available *ГНЕДЕНКО, Б. В. К теории областей притяжения устойчивых законов. Ученые записки МГУ, 1939, 2: 30.*)
  - and [Doeblin 1940](https://eudml.org/doc/219070), see theorem V in the freely available pdf.
- A slightly more exact description (in comparison to the wikipedia article) is given by https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Attraction_domain_of_a_stable_distribution